# Yii: how to show a field from a related table's related table?

Tags: yii

Sorry ... my english is bad, so my question could be absolutely not clear.

I have this tables:
Groups
Users
Reports

Relations:
**Groups 1 -> N Users 1 -> N Reports**

In the **admin view** of report I'm using a **CGridView**.

i'm actually able to show user name. ... but what about show group.name ?

How to setup relations ?
How to setup CDbCriteria ?

**I already have this relation** In Report model:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'userId'),
```

And this in User model

```
'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Gruppi', 'groupId'),
```

In Report Model I have this:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array ('user');
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show actual realtions

Comment: relation function in Report model?

Comment: what's a relational function ?! i've a Relation in report model, see the main post .

Comment: ah, sorry missed it the first time. OK you are using grid-view?

Comment: Yes I'm using the admin view with CGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the `group.name` like this(from report's admin view):

```
user.group.name
```

And your current relations will do, also you do not have to use any criteria.

Comment: Please:.. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873347/yii-how-to-sort-and-search-in-a-cgridview-column-with-a-two-level-1-n-relation

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this:-

```
$criteria->with = array('user', 'user.group');
group.name
```

One more solution for the problem. (Tested)