# How to sort and search in a CGridView column with a two-level 1-N relation?

Tags: yii, yii-relations

This question directly follow [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873087/yii-how-to-show-a-field-from-a-related-tables-related-table)

I have this tables: Groups, Users, Reports

Relations:
**Groups 1 -> N Users **  and ** Users 1 -> N Reports**

**I already have this relation** In Report model:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'userId'),
```

And this in User model

```
'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Gruppi', 'groupId'),
```

In Report Model I have this:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array ('user');
```

In the **admin view** of report I'm using a **CGridView**.

I'm using user.group.name for showing group name, but **how to search (by DropDown) and sort** !?

Comment: for this, check : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Comment: see my answer, I've extended the wiki solution adding the combo for searching, and extended the solution to cover the two-level relation problem ...

Comment: ok, that's nice, and it's ok to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was waiting for a confirm the my answer was valid and 'good code pratice'. (I must wait one onther day, and I'll can do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin view, instead of user.group.name, i'm using

```
array (
        'name' => 'groupId',
        'value' => '$data->user->group->name',
        'filter' => Chtml::listData( Groups::model()->findAll() ,'id','name')
    ),
```

In Report model I added a class field

```
public $groupId;
```

In Report rules

```
    array('groupId','safe','on'=>'search'),
```

In Report search

```
....
$criteria->with = array ('user.group');
....
$criteria->compare('user.groupId',$this->groupId);
....
[in sort array]
'groupId'=>array(
            'asc' =>'group.name',
                'desc'=>'group.name DESC',
 ),
```

In this way I can search, and sort, by group name !

I hope this post can be usefull to someon